# It is feasible that a (human) civilization at the end of time uses English, Latin, etc. words but considers earth history as a myth?

Tags: language, mythology

When universe is close to ending (only few solar systems remain), I can see how Earth history (or the current galactic civilization beginnings) could become a myth. However, does that mean that some words/expressions (e.g. Sun, Sol, Solar system, etc.) would also be discouraged? In a way, they were closely related to the original origin place that is almost forgotten.

Comment: At this end of time, I expect the real language to be so different that nobody would understand it. On the other hand, your audience reads English (or other modern day language). I would suggest just forgetting about the language, maybe making up a few slightly modified idioms.

Comment: It is a convention established thousands of years ago that the characters in a story speak the language of the audience. Of course, the audience *knows* that the characters would speak their own language, and that the story teller provides a translation; but this does not have to be made explicit, and most usually it isn't. For example, consider Virgil's *Aeneid*, written about 2,000 years ago: everybody speaks Latin, although the characters are Trojans, Carthaginians and so on, who wouldn't actually speak Latin; and the story takes place in a mythical past, when Latin was not yet spoken.

Comment: My concern is mixing words/names from other languages in that context. If using one language for everything then there is no problem, but when some foreign (or latin) words are used to represent things maybe is harder to justify. As a response says, maybe it's more about the semantics than where these words actually come from.

Answer (score 3):

Considering how much language changes in just a century or two, it doesn't seem at all feasible...

...but that has never stopped anybody from creating end-of-time stories before, and it shouldn't stop you now.

So don't flip your lid about cooking with gas on the lingo. Don't make the reader work to understand.

Comment: One of my concerns was to name a spaceship "Dies Irae", which probably is too much... specially if Earth is kind of a "myth".

Comment: It's not too much, if you want folks to assume that the ship owner is a crank or wierdo. Chekhov's Gun applies to such details.

Answer (score 2):

**It is feasible that a (human) civilization at the end of time uses English, Latin, etc. words?**

No, that is not feasible. Over that span of time, it would not be practical to trace the etymology of any words in end-time languages back to contemporary languages like English.

**When universe is close to ending (only few solar systems remain), I can see how Earth history (or the current galactic civilization beginnings) could become a myth. However, does that mean that some words/expressions (e.g. Sun, Sol, Solar system, etc.) would also be discouraged? In a way, they were closely related to the original origin place that is almost forgotten.**

Etymology is not semantics. If by some miracle you could trace the future-language words for those concepts back to English or Latin, that doesn't mean anyone would care. We use all sorts of words whose etymological origins are related to mythology we no longer believe in. If nobody even remembers it, that's just all the more reason for them to not care, let alone discourage use.

Comment: For a great reference to Far-future views on Human civilzations, please see Dr. Asimov's excellent *short* story " The Last Question", and for a much more comprehensive view his equally impressive ( but longer) "Foundation" series.  Both deal with time when "Earth" is considered as a 'myth',  and as you read, ask yourself, "Are any of my words today *Atlantean* in origin?"

Comment: Yeah, "The last question" is probably one of my favourite short stories. Quite related with the story I have in mind

Comment: I've also read foundation BTW. In my story Earth doesn't even exist anymore. Hell, even the Via Lactea (even 'Lactomeda') will be gone long time ago. I asume even then there would be some curiosity for future galactic civilizations to know where all started